# npm install express not fetching node_module

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to install express as server-side framework to work on a project and I am using bower as well for other front-end job. However, When I run npm install express it shows all the files without any error but when I cd into the directory, there is nothing; no node-modules or anything to work with. I googled it but there isn't any solution. Please check the following output -

```
npm install express


express@4.10.4 ../../node_modules/express
+-- utils-merge@1.0.0
+-- merge-descriptors@0.0.2
+-- fresh@0.2.4
+-- cookie@0.1.2
+-- escape-html@1.0.1
+-- range-parser@1.0.2
+-- cookie-signature@1.0.5
+-- finalhandler@0.3.2
+-- vary@1.0.0
+-- media-typer@0.3.0
+-- methods@1.1.0
+-- parseurl@1.3.0
+-- serve-static@1.7.1
+-- content-disposition@0.5.0
+-- path-to-regexp@0.1.3
+-- depd@1.0.0
+-- qs@2.3.3
+-- on-finished@2.1.1 (ee-first@1.1.0)
+-- etag@1.5.1 (crc@3.2.1)
+-- debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
+-- proxy-addr@1.0.4 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.5)
+-- send@0.10.1 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.6.2, mime@1.2.11)
+-- type-is@1.5.3 (mime-types@2.0.3)
+-- accepts@1.1.3 (negotiator@0.4.9, mime-types@2.0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Npm is saying you that express is in another folder, `../../node_modules/express` two levels above your current directory.

Maybe try specifying express in your package.json and do `npm install`